# WordPress Ajax is successful but function doesn't appear to run

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I've been googling this for a while and have tried a number of things (for example nesting my formName and formData in the 'data:' attribute, but that resulted in parseerrors, so I'm guessing I'm pretty close to having this working! I've also removed those attributes and hard coded the items in my function, but the problem remains the same.

Everything appears to be OK and I get by success alert, but when I check my database the usermeta hasn't been updated. I don't know the best way to debug the PHP function either so any tips on that would be handy for the future!!

This is my ajax function which get's fired on blur:

```
function storeData(data) {   

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        formData: data,
        formName: 'Testform',
        action: 'storeApplicationData',

        success:function( data ) {
            console.log('stored form');
        },
        error: function(xml, error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

This is my PHP code in my functions file, I've hard-coded the values I'm passing in to update_user_meta for now, just to ensure that isn't the issue:

```
function storeApplicationData(){
  update_user_meta('15', 'Testform', '12345678');
}
add_action('wp_ajax_storeApplicationData', 'storeApplicationData');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_storeApplicationData', 'storeApplicationData');
```

I'm checking the database directly, the meta field doesn't get updated...

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you don't have `alert()` function in your jQuery. can you confirm, that your ajax request is success with 200 server answer?

Comment: I figured it out (have posted my answer), and discovered where to see my PHP echos - it's in the network tab on my inspector!

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, I was missing the proper enqueing for my ajax url:

```
function theme_enqueue() {

    $theme_url  = get_template_directory_uri();     // Used to keep our Template Directory URL
    $ajax_url   = admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' );        // Localized AJAX URL

    // Register Our Script for Localization
    wp_register_script( 'applications', "{$theme_url}/applicationform.js", array( 'jquery' ),'1.0', true);

    // Localize Our Script so we can use `ajax_url`
    wp_localize_script('applications','ajax_url',$ajax_url);

    // Finally enqueue our script
    wp_enqueue_script( 'applications' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue' );
```

I also added:

```
url: ajax_url,
```

to my ajax!